# RemoteAttribute Validation passes the wrong value of AdditionalFields

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using a `RemoteAttribute` for some custom validation in my form. For simplicity, I have a radio group, `PrimarySupportingDocument`, with 3 options. If it is a certain selection the remote validation should validate that two textbox values, `VIN` and `TitleNumber`, match based on some (irrelevant) criteria.

In my **ViewModel**:

```
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("VIN")]
    public string VIN { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Primary Supporting Document")]
    public string PrimarySupportingDocument { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Title Number")]
    [Remote("VinAndTitleMatch", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "VIN and Title Number do not match", AdditionalFields = "VIN, PrimarySupportingDocument")]
    public string TitleNumber { get; set; }
```

In my **ValidationController**:

```
    public JsonResult VinAndTitleMatch(string titleNumber, string VIN, string primarySupportingDocument)
    {
        if (primarySupportingDocument == "In-State Title" && VIN != null && titleNumber != null)
        {


            if (/* test if vin and title number match */)
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            return Json("VIN and Title Number do not match", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Form Example:
[image: example of problem]

So, if you look at the request URL, you can see it is passing `In-State+Title` as the `PrimarySupportingDocument` value rather than the actual `:checked` value `Out of State Title`.

I did some research to see if the actual value being passed from `jquery.validate` was correct and found [this issue](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/363). This is not the problem, since its been fixed in 1.11.1 and I logged the output of the return value of the line :
`$("input[name='" + $(element).attr("name") + "']:checked").val()` which is returning the correct value but, I can't seem to figure out why it is not passing the checked value of the radio group.

Here is the rendered output of the radio group:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="PrimarySupportingDocument">Primary Supporting Document</label>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Primary Supporting Document field is required." id="PrimarySupportingDocument0" name="PrimarySupportingDocument" type="radio" value="In-State Title">In-State Title</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input id="PrimarySupportingDocument1" name="PrimarySupportingDocument" type="radio" value="Out of State Title">Out of State Title</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input id="PrimarySupportingDocument2" name="PrimarySupportingDocument" type="radio" value="None">None</label>
    </div> 
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PrimarySupportingDocument" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I was able to find the solution from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19850382/998320 this should be marked as a duplicate question but I am keeping it open in the hopes it will help others.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` doesn't support radio buttons! It doesn't filter by the `checked` attribute

```
adapters.add("remote", ["url", "type", "additionalfields"], function (options) {
    ...
    $.each(splitAndTrim(options.params.additionalfields || options.element.name), function (i, fieldName) {
        var paramName = appendModelPrefix(fieldName, prefix);
        value.data[paramName] = function () {
            return $(options.form).find(":input").filter("[name='" + escapeAttributeValue(paramName) + "']").val(); //problem here
        };
    });
    ...
});
```

Easiest way around this is to use `select` element instead of radio buttons

Comment: +1 thanks for your help, it guided me to a workaround. see my comment above